# Task timed out with ComputeTaskTimeoutException

Tags: java, ignite

Since I upgraded to Ignite 2.8.1 I'm frequently seeing timeouts on Ignite compute for Callables. This hasn't been the case with v2.7.6. I even never used the timeout option before because I never saw any delay in compute.

Since it's now often stuck in the compute().call() method I added withTimeout(60000) but still had to add a loop to try this several times before the function is actually called on any of the client nodes. This doesn't happen all times, but sometimes.

When it happens I see in the Ignite log messages like this:

```
[01:14:27,237][WARNING][grid-timeout-worker-#119][GridTaskWorker] Task has timed out: GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=de.my.comp.net.ignite.CreateNewMedia, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1609753866994, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5c29bfd, clsLdrId=06faeccc671-65368413-cf29-4a85-9f51-9b124c6a3351, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=de.my.comp.net.ignite.CreateNewMedia, sesId=7bccb2ec671-65368413-cf29-4a85-9f51-9b124c6a3351, startTime=1610586807229, endTime=1610586867229, taskNodeId=65368413-cf29-4a85-9f51-9b124c6a3351, clsLdr=jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5c29bfd, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=false, topPred=null, subjId=65368413-cf29-4a85-9f51-9b124c6a3351, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=null, hash=154761191]], execName=null]
```

This is now my code (shortened to be more readable):

```
while(something)
{
    ...
    ...
    final long   TASK_TIMEOUT_CREATENEWMEDIA     = 60 * 1000;
    
    ClusterGroup servers                         = IgniteHelper.getComputeNodes(ignite);
    UUID         thisMasterID                    = IgniteHelper.getLocalNodeID(ignite);
    
    IgniteSemaphore semaphore                    = ignite.semaphore("masterFindNodeSempahore", 1, true, true);
    
    try
    {
        semaphore.acquire();
        
        CreateNewMedia cnm = new CreateNewMedia(currentConfig, thisMasterID, currentJobID, msResubmit);
        CreateNewMediaResult result = ignite.compute(servers).withTimeout(TASK_TIMEOUT_CREATENEWMEDIA).call(cnm);
        
        ...
        ...
    }   
    catch (IgniteException e)
    {
        if (e instanceof ComputeTaskTimeoutException)
        {
            // log task timeout, try again if not max tries reached
            ...
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            // if some other issue, we better leave
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

The goal of this code is to find a node that is free to perform a specific action. The function returns if the node where it was executed is available. If it returns negative result, I remove this node ID from the list and try the remaining servers (this logic is not in the above code for simplicity).

It seems that setting publicThreadPoolSize to 512 reduced chances for the timeout to happen, but it still sometimes occur. If it occurs, in most cases it eventually calls the function after a few minutes, i.e. several tries to compute().call() in loop.

Is this known in Ignite 2.8.1? This is running on a server farm with 25 Ignite compute clients.

Workload on the client nodes is high but definitely not overloaded. Actually the nodes are mostly running an external cmdline executable while the Java portion is only waiting for its console output.

Any help appreciated.

Additional note: I've seen the timeout with v2.8.1 on other Callable's as well, so I don't think it's particularly related to the implementation of CreateNewMedia or of how it's been called in my sample code above.

Comment: I recommend collecting thread dumps at the moments when tasks are underway, see where they spend their time. Also, it's possible that CreateNewMedia is a large object (check its serialization graph) and so it will be stuck somewhere in communication.

Comment: It will be hard to catch thread dumps from the time when the issue happens since it's distributed on many servers and it can happen anywhere on the cluster. I will try. Data objects aren't that large, and classes are existing on client nodes.

Comment: Btw, what's the timeout about? Is it until the task has been successfully submitted and starts execution, or is until its computation is actually finished on the remote server? For compute().boadcast(IgniteClosure) will it be until *all* tasks haven been submitted or finished?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I think it's easier to fix the underlying problem here than to figure out the details of how compute works. Maybe there's something in the javadoc.